# calling a member function in an other member function to access a map matrix structure for OpenGL (SUMO, netedit)

Tags: c++, class, opengl

I want to call a member class from the type GNEEdge in an other class called GNEThread. They are both way different in their inherited classes and structure, so I always get an error that says I need to specify my called GNEEdge function, which I cant really do manually, because the Edges are created somewhere else and their data structure is too big, but I need the matrix information out of this GNEEdge class, so the called drawGL function needs the GNEEdge type. The whole reason I need to call it in GNEThread is that the code for creating a map is included there and I want to display some changing points in OpenGL while seeing the map.

```
void GNEEdge::drawGL(const GUIVisualizationSettings& s) const {

glPushName(getGlID());
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(210, 65, 5);
glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blau
GLHelper::drawFilledCircle(1.6, 5);
glPopMatrix();
glPopName();
```

}

I want to call it in this other function:

```
    FXint GNELoadThread::run() {
//here is some code for creating the map
//in here the GNEEdge::DrawGL member function should be called
//so in the end I can change some viewed points while the map 
//is already displayed via loops
}
```

Is it even possible to have this kind of connection between two .cpp files?(I mean inheritence doesn't really work,because I  then get constructor errors) Or for displaying non-static points in a loaded map I need specific OpenGL render functions?

Comment: In `GNELoadThread::run` do you have an instance of the `GNEEdge` class? Do you have an `GUIVisualizationSettings` instance that you can use in the call? Then just call the function?

Comment: That is exactly the problem, i don't have a instance of GNEEdge in GNELoadThread; because the data structure to create something like that is ways too big; so things like GNEEdge g(.,.,.,.,); g.drawGL(s) won't work. I need the matrix information of the map and in the GNEEdge constructor where the edges are created I already have that. Is there like a option with pointer structures or things similar, to call something in a other .cpp member function without to really specifing it...

Comment: How about a *reference* to a `GNEEDge` object?

Comment: How would you realize this reference call? And how would the function pointer to the member class look, i mean i read about it, but trying it by looking at example cases still gives me many errors, i don' get it..

Comment: Not a "reference call", but a reference variable. Look, the `run` function *must* have access to an `GNEEdge` object instance, through a copy, a reference, or a pointer (it doesn't matter really), but it must have one. Otherwise you simply can not call functions in that class. You might want to consider a redesign of your project?

Comment: yes thank you, I guess will think about an other solution:)